# Android App got stuck when posting comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I tried to post a comment on an answer and the app seemed to get stuck on the "Posting comment" popup. I tried to use the back button to cancel the posting so I could retry but pressing back did nothing, I had to manually force close the app. When I had reloaded the app the commenting worked as expected.

So the bug is perhaps the fact the commenting didn't work and got stuck, the feature request(s) would be a timeout so if it didn't work it could cancel and/or having the back button close the dialog.

Comment: I think this is just a [tag:bug] then. Implied in the reporting of the bug is the desire for something to be done to fix it.

Comment: HTTP time out is must/necessary for all the web operation.

Comment: @Duncan True! The timeout would be a fix but then perhaps the back button cancelling the dialogue would be a feature request, or I guess it could be seen as a fix if the timeout wasn't implemented. The team can always delete the feature-request tag if it's not considered appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to the fact that comment posting was happening on the UI thread rather than in a background operation, so if it was taking a long time it'd freeze up the entire application. This has been fixed prior to version 1.0.